# Writing a char array based on instructions from a file

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, char

I need to fill an char array so that it looks like this:

```
char* str[3] = {"tex.png", "text2.png", "tex3.png"};`
```

I need to load all that from a file which looks like this:

```
TEXDEF 0 Resources/Textures/tex.png

TEXDEF 1 Resources/Textures/tex2.png

TEXDEF 2 Resources/Textures/tex3.png
```

So far, I have:

```
char* texs[3];
char* tstr;
int tnum;

sscanf_s(oneline, "TEXDEF %d %s", &tnum, &tstr);

texs[tnum] = tstr;  // Problem?
```

My problem appears to happen at the last line. The compiler gives me no errors, but when I run the program, it causes an unhandled exception and points to that line.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this homework?  Is it really C++ not C given your talking about sscanf?

Comment: If you are tagging C++, why not use c++?  This is pretty much straight C and you are making it harder than if you just used basic C++ facilities.

Comment: Are the values of `tnum` guaranteed to be in sequential order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to fill an char array so that it looks like this:

No you don't. This is C++, so use `std::string`.

```
std::array<std::string, 3> filenames;

std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
std::string line;

for (unsigned int i = 0; std::getline(infile, line); ++i)
{
  std::string tok1, tok3;
  unsigned int tok2;

  if (!(infile >> tok1 >> tok2 >> tok3)) { /* input error! */ }

  if (tok1 != "TEXDEF" || tok2 != i || i > 2) { /* format error */ }

  filenames[i] = tok3;
}
```

If the number of file names is variable, you can just replace the array by `std::vector<std::string>` and omit the `i > 2` range check.

Comment: Finally, +1. Though, couldn't tok2 be an int to make things simpler?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Just to be pedantic: how would you handle filenames with spaces... +1 (for fun added a spirit based answer :))

Comment: @sehe: With difficulty! :-) I might resort to `line.substr(8)` in a crunch.

Comment: @KerrekSB: actually I do need it to be a char array, I'm using some libraries that were written in c

Comment: @PgrAm: Read up the `std::string` interface; it has a `c_str()` accessor function for such purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, your program is crashing because you never allocate memory for your character arrays.  Moreover, `sscanf_s()` expects two arguments for each `%s` token in the format string.  It needs both a pointer to the buffer *and* the buffer's size (this is to avoid buffer overruns).

You would have to pass a pointer a an array of characters to `sscanf_s()`, something like:

```
char tstr[3][MAX_PATH]; // replace `MAX_PATH` by proper maximum size.
sscanf_s(oneline, "TEXDEF %d %s", &tnum, tstr[0], MAX_PATH);
sscanf_s(oneline, "TEXDEF %d %s", &tnum, tstr[1], MAX_PATH);
sscanf_s(oneline, "TEXDEF %d %s", &tnum, tstr[2], MAX_PATH);
```

However, this is really a pain to manage by hand.  Using `std::vector<>`, `std::string` and `std::ifstream` is likely to be much easier as memory will automatically be managed.

```
std::ifstream file("path/to/file.txt");
std::vector<std::string> inputs;
// assuming one entry on each line.
for (std::string line; std::getline(file,line); )
{
    // extract components on the line.
    std::istringstream input(line);
    std::string texdef;
    int index = 0;
    std::string path;
    input >> texdef;
    input >> index;
    std::getline(input, path);
    // if the results may appear out of order,
    // insert at `index` instead of at the end.
    inputs.push_back(path);
}
```

Comment: He can't do `tstr[0]` and stuff because the file tells him what index to use.

Comment: Indeed, but It's not clear if the elements can appear out of order.  Until OP gives a clearer description of the file format, it's the best we can do.  If the elements are non-sequential and out of order, it might be a better idea to use a `std::map<>`.

Comment: From msdn:Unlike the less secure version sscanf, a buffer size parameter sizeOfBuffer is required when using the type field characters c, C, s, S and [. This parameter must be supplied as an additional parameter after each buffer which requires it.

Comment: This simple question turned out to be not as trivial as it appeared at first glance. None of the answers so far are completely correct.

Comment: @RomanB.: indeed, I hadn't even notice OP wasn't using plain old `scanf()`.  I'll fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

*Mandatory* answer based on Boost Spirit:

Main:

```
typedef std::map<size_t, std::string> Result;

// ...
const std::string input = // TODO read from file :)
    "TEXDEF 1 Resources/Textures/tex2.png\n"
    "TEXDEF 0 Resources/Textures/tex.png\n"
    "TEXDEF 2 Resources/Textures/tex3.png";

Result result;
if (doTest(input, result))
{
    std::cout << "Parse results: " << std::endl;

    for (Result::const_iterator it = result.begin(); it!= result.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << "Mapped: " << it->first << " to " << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Parse results: 
Mapped: 0 to Resources/Textures/tex.png
Mapped: 1 to Resources/Textures/tex2.png
Mapped: 2 to Resources/Textures/tex3.png
```

Full code:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef std::map<size_t, std::string> Result;

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper> struct TexDefs
  : qi::grammar<Iterator, Result(), Skipper>
{
    TexDefs()
      : TexDefs::base_type(texdefs)
    {
        texdefs  = def >> *(qi::eol >> def);
        def      = "TEXDEF" >> key >> filename;
        key      = qi::uint_;
        filename = qi::lexeme [ +(qi::char_ - qi::eol) ];
    }
    typedef Result::key_type    key_t;
    typedef Result::mapped_type value_t;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Result(), Skipper>        texdefs;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::pair<key_t, value_t>(), Skipper> def;
    qi::rule<Iterator, key_t(), Skipper>         key;
    qi::rule<Iterator, value_t(), Skipper>       filename;
};

template <typename Input, typename Skip>
   bool doTest(const Input& input, Result& into, const Skip& skip)
{
    typedef typename Input::const_iterator It;
    It first(input.begin()), last(input.end());

    TexDefs<It, Skip> parser;

    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(first, last, parser, skip, into);

    if (!ok)         std::cerr << "Parse failed at '" << std::string(first, last) << "'" << std::endl;
    if (first!=last) std::cerr << "Warning: remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'" << std::endl;

    return ok;
}

template <typename Input>
bool doTest(const Input& input, Result& into)
{
    // allow whitespace characters :)
    return doTest(input, into, qi::char_(" \t"));
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const std::string input = // TODO read from file :)
        "TEXDEF 1 Resources/Textures/tex2.png\n"
        "TEXDEF 0 Resources/Textures/tex.png\n"
        "TEXDEF 2 Resources/Textures/tex3.png";

    Result result;
    if (doTest(input, result))
    {
        std::cout << "Parse results: " << std::endl;

        for (Result::const_iterator it = result.begin(); it!= result.end(); ++it)
            std::cout << "Mapped: " << it->first << " to " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You just scared the hell out of OP. :)

Comment: @jrok And about 80% of the other viewers. ;)

Comment: You are what they call an "extremist".

Comment: @KerrekSB: Nah - I just abuse SO to get some exercise in Spirit; a lot actually :)

Answer (score 0):

When reading into a string, you must prepare a buffer and pass a pointer to that buffer to `sscanf_s`. Passing the address of a `char *` variable won't work. Also, you should use the length-restricted form, e.g., `%255s` for a 256-byte buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [basic] C++ instead:

```
std::ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
std::vector<std::string> lines;

if(myfile.is_open())
{
    for(std::string line; std::getline(myfile, line); )
    {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    myfile.close();
}
else
{
    cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

To parse and print the data, just loop through the `lines` like an array:

```
std::map<int, std::string> data;

for(size_t i = 0; i < lines.length(); ++i)
{
    int n;
    std::string s;
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << lines[i].substr(((static std::string const)"TEXDEF ").length());
    ss >> n >> s;

    data[n] = s;

    // Print.
    std::cout << lines[i] << "\n";
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

I recommend you read [this `std::map` tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/stlmap.html).

---

> ### Resources
>
> [Basic File I/O](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)
>   [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)

Comment: This will add an empty string as the last element of the vector when `getline` fails. It should be `while (getline(...))`

Comment: Note that `.good()` followed by `getline()` will break if the file is finished by a newline, in which case the last entry in the vector will be empty.

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that the index to write to comes from the file. Unless sequential ordering is guaranteed, you can't just use a series of `push_back` calls.

Comment: Why the gratuitous `std::string line = "";`? That smells like cargo cult programming (or voodoo). `std::string line;` is enough.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Addressed while making it as simple as possible. (I hope.)

Comment: @muntoo: You believe in your heart that `std::string("TEXDEF ").length()` is faster than `7`?

Comment: @muntoo: Very unlikely. `std::string` has no `char(&)[N]` overload, so that's not a constant expression.

Comment: @muntoo: also brutally incorrect. At the very least make the magic string a static constant.

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh, right. At least a good compiler can optimize *this*. :)